# Entity MVC and ViewModels one to many example

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, viewmodel

I have a simple example

I want to display a list of companies and employees

```
ACME
    David
    Simon
    Zac
Microsoft
    Kevin
    Paul
```

Currently I do a linq query that returns the company model then traverse the model tree to get the employees. This works fine, however using glimpse I see its doing in the above example 3 queries. One for company then 2 queries for employees one for each company.

Im wondering if I would be better off having a ViewModel representing the data and populating that. However when trying to build the view model I dont know how to build it without doing multiple queries.

```
var data =
    from company in db.Companies
    join employee in db.Employees on company.companyId equals employee.companyId
    orderby company.name, employee.name
    select new { companyName = company.name, employeeName = employee.name }
```

Is there an easy way to link this to the view model or is there another best practice way of doing something simple like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get data in one round trip from database by adding `ToList()`:

```
var data =
(from company in db.Companies
join employee in db.Employees on company.companyId equals employee.companyId
orderby company.name, employee.name
select new { companyName = company.name, employeeName = employee.name }).ToList();
```

or get company type instead of anonymous type

```
var data = db.Companies.Include(t => t.Employees )
            .Select(t => new
            {
                t.name,
                Employees = t.Employees .Select(p => new { p.name})
            }).ToList();
```

or if you wanna use ViewModel, create a viewmodel:

```
public class CompanyVm
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees{ get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

then use automapper to map data

```
var comVm = data
            .Select(comp => AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap(comp, comp.GetType(), typeof(CompanyVm)))
            .Select(comp => comp as CompanyVm).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the navigation properties in Entity Framework wired up correctly, you should be able to do:

```
var data = db.Companies
  .Include(i => i.Employees)
  .Tolist();
```

Then you can loop through them:

```
foreach (var company in data)
{
  foreach (var employee in company.Employees)
  {
  }
}
```

Don't forget to include `using System.Data.Entity;` or you won't be able to use the strong-typed `.Include()` method.

Comment: Not sure how this is a ViewModel example